UniswapV3 deployment issue, <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown>
I am trying to deploy uniswapV3 contracts locally and testing adding liquidity/swapping.
I am using V3's 0.8 version (solidity compiler 0.8.15) with hardhat 2.14.0.
When I deployed the contracts and trying to call 'mint' function in nonfungiblePositionManager.sol, I got error:
 Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x0165878a594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242eb8f) at EdrProviderWrapper.request (/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:415:41) at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
Below is my test.js code. I really don't see where the problem is... I made sure the token with smaller address is token0, and I managed to deploy all related contracts before minting. So where could the problem lie... Thanks ahead.
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {formatEther, parseEther} = require("ethers/lib/utils");
const {ContractFactory, utils} = require("ethers");
const { Contract, BigNumber } = require("ethers")
const bn = require('bignumber.js')

let data = []
function addToData(name, addr){
    data.push({contract_name : name, address: addr})
}
function getData(){
    console.table(data)
}

function encodePriceSqrt(reserve1, reserve0) {
    const bnReserve1 = new bn(reserve1.toString());
    const bnReserve0 = new bn(reserve0.toString());
    const sqrtPrice = bnReserve1.div(bnReserve0).sqrt();
    const scaledSqrtPrice = sqrtPrice.multipliedBy(new bn(2).pow(96)); // Scale by 2^96
    // Convert to a string without scientific notation
    const scaledSqrtPriceStr = scaledSqrtPrice.integerValue(bn.ROUND_FLOOR).toFixed(0);
    // Return as a BigNumber from ethers.js
    return BigNumber.from(scaledSqrtPriceStr.toString());
}

const artifacts = {
    UniswapV3Factory: require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json"),
    SwapRouter: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/SwapRouter.sol/SwapRouter.json"),
    NFTDescriptor: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol/NFTDescriptor.json"),
    NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.sol/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.json"),
    NonfungiblePositionManager: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
    WETH9: require('/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/artifacts/contracts/WETH9.sol/WETH9.json'),
    Usdt: require('/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/artifacts/contracts/demoToken.sol/demoToken.json'),
    Token: require('/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/artifacts/contracts/demoToken.sol/demoToken2.json'),
    UniswapV3Pool:require('/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/artifacts/contracts/v3-core/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json'),
    QuoteV2: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/lens/QuoterV2.sol/QuoterV2.json"),
};

const linkLibraries = ({ bytecode, linkReferences }, libraries) => {
    Object.keys(linkReferences).forEach((fileName) => {
        Object.keys(linkReferences[fileName]).forEach((contractName) => {
            if (!libraries.hasOwnProperty(contractName)) {
                throw new Error(`Missing link library name ${contractName}`)
            }
            const address = utils
                .getAddress(libraries[contractName])
                .toLowerCase()
                .slice(2)
            linkReferences[fileName][contractName].forEach(
                ({ start, length }) => {
                    const start2 = 2 + start * 2
                    const length2 = length * 2
                    bytecode = bytecode
                        .slice(0, start2)
                        .concat(address)
                        .concat(bytecode.slice(start2 + length2, bytecode.length))
                }
            )
        })
    })
    return bytecode
}

async function getPoolData(poolContract) {
    const [tickSpacing, fee, liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
        poolContract.tickSpacing(),
        poolContract.fee(),
        poolContract.liquidity(),
        poolContract.slot0(),
    ])

    return {
        tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
        fee: fee,
        liquidity: liquidity,
        sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
        tick: slot0[1],
    }
}

async function deployPool(token0, token1, fee, price) {

    await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer[0]).createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
        price,
        {gasLimit: '5000000'}
    )
    const _poolAddress = await factory.getPool(
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
    )
    return _poolAddress
}

describe("Test", function () {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        signer = await ethers.getSigners()
        accounts = signer.map(item => item.address)

        const Weth = new ContractFactory(artifacts.WETH9.abi, artifacts.WETH9.bytecode, signer[0]);
        weth = await Weth.deploy();

        const Factory = new ContractFactory(artifacts.UniswapV3Factory.abi, artifacts.UniswapV3Factory.bytecode, signer[0]);
        factory = await Factory.deploy();

        const SwapRouter = new ContractFactory(artifacts.SwapRouter.abi, artifacts.SwapRouter.bytecode, signer[0]);
        swapRouter = await SwapRouter.deploy(factory.address, weth.address);

        const NFTDescriptor = new ContractFactory(artifacts.NFTDescriptor.abi, artifacts.NFTDescriptor.bytecode, signer[0]);
        nftDescriptor = await NFTDescriptor.deploy();

        const QuoteV2 = new ContractFactory(artifacts.QuoteV2.abi, artifacts.QuoteV2.bytecode, signer[0]);
        quoteV2 = await QuoteV2.deploy(factory.address, weth.address);

        const linkedBytecode = linkLibraries(
            {
                bytecode: artifacts.NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.bytecode,
                linkReferences: {
                    "NFTDescriptor.sol": {
                        NFTDescriptor: [
                            {
                                length: 20,
                                start: 1681,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                NFTDescriptor: nftDescriptor.address,
            }
        );

        const NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor = new ContractFactory(artifacts.NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.abi, linkedBytecode, signer[0]);

        const nativeCurrencyLabelBytes = utils.formatBytes32String('WETH')
        nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor = await NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.deploy(weth.address, nativeCurrencyLabelBytes);
        // console.log(factory.address, weth.address, nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.address)

        const NonfungiblePositionManager = new ContractFactory(artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi, artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.bytecode, signer[0]);
        nonfungiblePositionManager = await NonfungiblePositionManager.deploy(factory.address, weth.address, nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.address);

        const Usdt = new ContractFactory(artifacts.Usdt.abi, artifacts.Usdt.bytecode, signer[0])
        usdt = await Usdt.deploy()

        const Token = new ContractFactory(artifacts.Token.abi, artifacts.Token.bytecode, signer[0])
        token = await Token.deploy()

        addToData('WETH_ADDRESS', weth.address)
        addToData('FACTORY_ADDRESS', factory.address)
        addToData('SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS', swapRouter.address)
        addToData('NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS', nftDescriptor.address)
        addToData('POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS', nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.address)
        addToData('POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS', nonfungiblePositionManager.address)
        addToData('USDT_ADDRESS', usdt.address)
        addToData('TOKEN_ADDRESS', token.address)
        getData(data)

        const poolAddress = await deployPool(token.address, usdt.address, 500, encodePriceSqrt(1, 1))

        addToData('POOL_ADDRESS', poolAddress)


        const poolContract = new Contract(poolAddress, artifacts.UniswapV3Pool.abi, signer[0])
        let poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)
        console.log('pooldata is ',poolData)

        await token.connect(signer[0]).transfer(accounts[1], parseEther('10000'))
        await usdt.connect(signer[0]).transfer(accounts[1], parseEther('10000'))
        await token.connect(signer[1]).approve(nonfungiblePositionManager.address, parseEther('100000'))
        await usdt.connect(signer[1]).approve(nonfungiblePositionManager.address, parseEther('100000'))

        console.log('token.address < usdt.address', token.address < usdt.address)
        const params = {
            token0: token.address,
            token1: usdt.address,
            fee: poolData.fee,
            tickLower: -2000,
            tickUpper: 2000,
            amount0Desired: ethers.utils.parseEther('10000'),
            amount1Desired: ethers.utils.parseEther('10000'),
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: accounts[1],
            deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)
        }

        console.log(typeof params.amount0Desired)
        //add liquidity
        try {
            await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer[1]).mint(
                params,
                {gasLimit: '20000000'}
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    })
    it("test", async function () {



    });

});

this is the info returned in my console
 Test
┌─────────┬───────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │         contract_name         │                   address                    │
├─────────┼───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │        'WETH_ADDRESS'         │ '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3' │
│    1    │       'FACTORY_ADDRESS'       │ '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512' │
│    2    │     'SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS'     │ '0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0' │
│    3    │   'NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS'    │ '0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9' │
│    4    │ 'POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS' │ '0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707' │
│    5    │  'POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS'   │ '0x0165878A594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242Eb8F' │
│    6    │        'USDT_ADDRESS'         │ '0xa513E6E4b8f2a923D98304ec87F64353C4D5C853' │
│    7    │        'TOKEN_ADDRESS'        │ '0x2279B7A0a67DB372996a5FaB50D91eAA73d2eBe6' │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
pooldata is  {
  tickSpacing: 10,
  fee: 500,
  liquidity: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  sqrtPriceX96: BigNumber { value: "79228162514264337593543950336" },
  tick: 0
}
token.address < usdt.address true
object
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x0165878a594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242eb8f)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:415:41)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/adam/IdeaProjects/AdamMain/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
    ✔ test


I tried to deploy contracts using
const NonfungiblePositionManager = await ethers.getContractFactory(
            "NonfungiblePositionManager");
        const nonfungiblePositionManager = await NonfungiblePositionManager.deploy(factory.address, weth.address, Ntpd.address);
        await nonfungiblePositionManager.deployed();

and got

     Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at NonfungiblePositionManager.mint (contracts/v3-periphery/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol:128)
    at NonfungiblePositionManager.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary (contracts/v3-periphery/base/PoolInitializer.sol:26)
    at NonfungiblePositionManager.mint (contracts/v3-periphery/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol:141)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:415:41)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)



TETHER_ADDRESS= '0x62361474836856984730ce4d8E2a540f28D00277' USDC_ADDRESS= '0x80a8fe9589324BC311871Adc4D5697F3F0a87Fdd' WRAPPED_BITCOIN_ADDRESS= '0xa51Dc2F7f45e99485B4C4738c1544CA3cED7404B' WETH_ADDRESS= '0x38ef9AB9b2E0CfBA2E80c3Fd14A75D1348bD2f6B' FACTORY_ADDRESS= '0xA2e3adA27bad86eE4aA65ADC2F250995d18Df59B' SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS= '0x549b7e2761bFCf96CeBF7b7E1825108b718b2392' NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0x72D2742b7Ac875fCa2C616cB15bbac8af588e0a5' POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0xf85f49521BF93c3381f172Ac2320aa5B89a3eFC9' POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS= '0x9f30f749Dfe5ee31f47bC9FfbFfbdaE9958b37Ae' USDT_USDC_500 = "0xA03A92038FA26F43873b2dFA3c364A735968F685"


const artifacts = {   NonfungiblePositionManager: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"), Usdt: require("../artifacts/contracts/Tether.sol/Tether.json"),   Usdc: require("../artifacts/contracts/UsdCoin.sol/UsdCoin.json"),   UniswapV3Pool: require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json"), };

const { Contract } = require("ethers") const { Token } = require('@uniswap/sdk-core') const { Pool, Position, nearestUsableTick } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk')

async function getPoolData(poolContract) {   const [tickSpacing, fee, liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
    poolContract.tickSpacing(),
    poolContract.fee(),
    poolContract.liquidity(),
    poolContract.slot0(),   ])

  return {
    tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
    fee: fee,
    liquidity: liquidity,
    sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
    tick: slot0[1],   } }


async function main() {   const [_owner, signer2] = await ethers.getSigners();


  const provider = ethers.provider

  const usdtContract = new Contract(TETHER_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdt.abi,provider)   const usdcContract = new Contract(USDC_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdc.abi,provider)

  await usdtContract.connect(_owner).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS, ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'), { gasLimit: 5000000 })   await usdcContract.connect(_owner).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'),{ gasLimit: 5000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('20', 'gwei') });

  console.log("--------------- Token Approved ------------");

  const poolContract = new Contract(USDT_USDC_500, artifacts.UniswapV3Pool.abi, provider)

  const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)

  const UsdtToken = new Token(4440, TETHER_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDT', 'Tether')   console.log("UsdtToken ====>>",UsdtToken);   const UsdcToken = new Token(4440, USDC_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDC', 'UsdCoin')   console.log("UsdcToken ====>>",UsdcToken);

  const pool = new Pool(
    UsdtToken,
    UsdcToken,
    poolData.fee,
    poolData.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
    poolData.liquidity.toString(),
    poolData.tick   )

  const position = new Position({
    pool: pool,
    liquidity: ethers.utils.parseEther('1'),
    tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,   })

  const { amount0: amount0Desired, amount1: amount1Desired} = position.mintAmounts


  params = {
    token0: TETHER_ADDRESS,
    token1: USDC_ADDRESS,
    fee: poolData.fee,
    tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    amount0Desired: amount0Desired.toString(),
    amount1Desired: amount1Desired.toString(),
    amount0Min: 0,
    amount1Min: 0,
    recipient: _owner.address,
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)   }

  const nonfungiblePositionManager = new Contract(
    POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,
    artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi,
    provider   )

  console.log("Params -->",params);


console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

  const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(_owner).mint(
    params,
    { gasLimit: 5000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('30', 'gwei') }   )   await tx.wait()

  console.log("Liquidity Added Successfully "); }

/*   npx hardhat run --network taral scripts/04_addLiquidity.js
*/

main()   .then(() => process.exit(0))   .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);   });


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

> ***Use this code... Everything working fine in this code***
> 
> 
> 
> - > **package.json**   
>    > 
>    > 
>    > {   "name": "hardhat-v3-deploy",   "version": "1.0.0",  
>    > "description": "",   "main": "index.js",   "scripts": {
>    >     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "dependencies":
>    > {
>    >     "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.1.1",
>    >     "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
>    >     "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.3",
>    >     "@uniswap/v3-periphery": "^1.0.1",
>    >     "@uniswap/v3-sdk": "^3.9.0",
>    >     "bignumber.js": "^9.1.0",
>    >     "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
>    >     "ethers": "^5.7.1",
>    >     "hardhat": "^2.11.2"   } }
>    
>        **hardhat.config.js**
>        require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle"); const { utils } =    require('ethers');
>        /** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */    module.exports = {   solidity: {
>        version: "0.8.17",
>        settings: {
>          optimizer: {
>            enabled: true,
>            runs: 5000,
>            details: { yul: false },
>          },    }   },   networks: {
>        taral: {
>          chainId: ChainID,
>          url: "Your_RPC_URL",
>          accounts: ["your_private_key"],
>        },   }, };
> 
> 
> **deployPools.js**
> 
> 
> // Token addresses TETHER_ADDRESS=
> '0x62361474836856984730ce4d8E2a540f28D00277' USDC_ADDRESS=
> '0x80a8fe9589324BC311871Adc4D5697F3F0a87Fdd' WRAPPED_BITCOIN_ADDRESS=
> '0xa51Dc2F7f45e99485B4C4738c1544CA3cED7404B'
> 
> // Uniswap contract address WETH_ADDRESS=
> '0x38ef9AB9b2E0CfBA2E80c3Fd14A75D1348bD2f6B' FACTORY_ADDRESS=
> '0xA2e3adA27bad86eE4aA65ADC2F250995d18Df59B' SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS=
> '0x549b7e2761bFCf96CeBF7b7E1825108b718b2392' NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS=
> '0x72D2742b7Ac875fCa2C616cB15bbac8af588e0a5'
> POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS=
> '0xf85f49521BF93c3381f172Ac2320aa5B89a3eFC9' POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS=
> '0x9f30f749Dfe5ee31f47bC9FfbFfbdaE9958b37Ae'
> 
> const artifacts = {   UniswapV3Factory:
> require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json"),
> NonfungiblePositionManager:
> require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
> };
> 
> const { Contract, BigNumber } = require("ethers") const bn =
> require('bignumber.js') bn.config({ EXPONENTIAL_AT: 999999,
> DECIMAL_PLACES: 40 })
> 
> const provider = waffle.provider;
> 
> function encodePriceSqrt(reserve1, reserve0) {   return
> BigNumber.from(
>     new bn(reserve1.toString())
>       .div(reserve0.toString())
>       .sqrt()
>       .multipliedBy(new bn(2).pow(96))
>       .integerValue(3)
>       .toString()   ) }
> 
> const nonfungiblePositionManager = new Contract(  
> POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,   artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi, 
> provider ) const factory = new Contract(   FACTORY_ADDRESS,  
> artifacts.UniswapV3Factory.abi,   provider )
> 
> async function deployPool(token0, token1, fee, price) {   const
> [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();   await
> nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(owner).createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
>     token0,
>     token1,
>     fee,
>     price,
>     { gasLimit: 5000000 }   )   const poolAddress = await factory.connect(owner).getPool(
>     token0,
>     token1,
>     fee,   )   return poolAddress }
> 
> 
> async function main() {   const usdtUsdc500 = await
> deployPool(TETHER_ADDRESS, USDC_ADDRESS, 500, encodePriceSqrt(1, 1))  
> console.log('USDT_USDC_500=', `'${usdtUsdc500}'`) }
> 
> /* npx hardhat run --network taral scripts/03_deployPools.js
> */
> 
> main()   .then(() => process.exit(0))   .catch((error) => {
>     console.error(error);
>     process.exit(1);   });
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> >        **addLiquidity.js**
> 
> 
> >        TETHER_ADDRESS= '0x62361474836856984730ce4d8E2a540f28D00277'    USDC_ADDRESS= '0x80a8fe9589324BC311871Adc4D5697F3F0a87Fdd'   
> > WRAPPED_BITCOIN_ADDRESS= '0xa51Dc2F7f45e99485B4C4738c1544CA3cED7404B' 
> > WETH_ADDRESS= '0x38ef9AB9b2E0CfBA2E80c3Fd14A75D1348bD2f6B'   
> > FACTORY_ADDRESS= '0xA2e3adA27bad86eE4aA65ADC2F250995d18Df59B'   
> > SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS= '0x549b7e2761bFCf96CeBF7b7E1825108b718b2392'   
> > NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0x72D2742b7Ac875fCa2C616cB15bbac8af588e0a5'  
> > POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS=   
> > '0xf85f49521BF93c3381f172Ac2320aa5B89a3eFC9'   
> > POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS=   
> > '0x9f30f749Dfe5ee31f47bC9FfbFfbdaE9958b37Ae' USDT_USDC_500 =   
> > "0xA03A92038FA26F43873b2dFA3c364A735968F685"
> >    
> >        const artifacts = {   NonfungiblePositionManager:    require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
> > Usdt: require("../artifacts/contracts/Tether.sol/Tether.json"),     
> > Usdc: require("../artifacts/contracts/UsdCoin.sol/UsdCoin.json"),     
> > UniswapV3Pool:   
> > require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json"),
> > };
> >        const { Contract } = require("ethers") const { Token } =    require('@uniswap/sdk-core') const { Pool, Position,   
> > nearestUsableTick } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk')
> >        async function getPoolData(poolContract) {   const [tickSpacing, fee,    liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
> >        poolContract.tickSpacing(),
> >        poolContract.fee(),
> >        poolContract.liquidity(),
> >        poolContract.slot0(),   ])
> >    
> >      return {
> >        tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
> >        fee: fee,
> >        liquidity: liquidity,
> >        sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
> >        tick: slot0[1],   } }
> >    
> >        async function main() {   const [_owner, signer2] = await    ethers.getSigners();
> >    
> >    
> >      const provider = ethers.provider
> >    
> >      const usdtContract = new    Contract(TETHER_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdt.abi,provider)   const   
> > usdcContract = new Contract(USDC_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdc.abi,provider)
> >    
> >      await    usdtContract.connect(_owner).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,   
> > ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'), { gasLimit: 5000000 })   await   
> > usdcContract.connect(_owner).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'),{
> > gasLimit: 5000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('20', 'gwei')   
> > });
> >    
> >      console.log("--------------- Token Approved ------------");
> >    
> >      const poolContract = new Contract(USDT_USDC_500,    artifacts.UniswapV3Pool.abi, provider)
> >    
> >      const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)
> >    
> >      const UsdtToken = new Token(4440, TETHER_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDT',    'Tether')   console.log("UsdtToken ====>>",UsdtToken);   const   
> > UsdcToken = new Token(4440, USDC_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDC', 'UsdCoin')     
> > console.log("UsdcToken ====>>",UsdcToken);
> >    
> >      const pool = new Pool(
> >        UsdtToken,
> >        UsdcToken,
> >        poolData.fee,
> >        poolData.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
> >        poolData.liquidity.toString(),
> >        poolData.tick   )
> >    
> >      const position = new Position({
> >        pool: pool,
> >        liquidity: ethers.utils.parseEther('1'),
> >        tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
> >        tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,   })
> >    
> >      const { amount0: amount0Desired, amount1: amount1Desired} =    position.mintAmounts
> >    
> >    
> >      params = {
> >        token0: TETHER_ADDRESS,
> >        token1: USDC_ADDRESS,
> >        fee: poolData.fee,
> >        tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
> >        tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
> >        amount0Desired: amount0Desired.toString(),
> >        amount1Desired: amount1Desired.toString(),
> >        amount0Min: 0,
> >        amount1Min: 0,
> >        recipient: _owner.address,
> >        deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)   }
> >    
> >      const nonfungiblePositionManager = new Contract(
> >        POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,
> >        artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi,
> >        provider   )
> >    
> >      console.log("Params -->",params);
> >    
> >        console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
> >    
> >      const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(_owner).mint(
> >        params,
> >        { gasLimit: 5000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('30', 'gwei') }   )   await tx.wait()
> >    
> >      console.log("Liquidity Added Successfully "); }
> >        /*   npx hardhat run --network taral scripts/04_addLiquidity.js    */
> >        main()   .then(() => process.exit(0))   .catch((error) => {
> >        console.error(error);
> >        process.exit(1);   });
> 
> 
> 
> 
> >        **checkLiquidity.js**
> 
> 
> 
> >        USDT_USDC_500 = "0xA03A92038FA26F43873b2dFA3c364A735968F685"
> >        const { Contract } = require("ethers") const UniswapV3Pool =    require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json")
> >        async function getPoolData(poolContract) {   const [tickSpacing, fee,    liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
> >        poolContract.tickSpacing(),
> >        poolContract.fee(),
> >        poolContract.liquidity(),
> >        poolContract.slot0(),   ])
> >    
> >      return {
> >        tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
> >        fee: fee,
> >        liquidity: liquidity.toString(),
> >        sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
> >        tick: slot0[1],   } }
> >        async function main() {   const provider = ethers.provider
> >    
> >      const poolContract = new Contract(USDT_USDC_500, UniswapV3Pool.abi,    provider)
> >    
> >      const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)      console.log('poolData', poolData) }
> >        /*   npx hardhat run --network taral scripts/05_checkLiquidity.js    */
> >        main()   .then(() => process.exit(0))   .catch((error) => {
> >        console.error(error);
> >        process.exit(1);   });


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your script is a totally different way of dealing with the issue. I am glad it works. For now I am still trying to figure out the problem with my code here, I will probably use your method in the later future. Anyway I really appreciate your code!
